# Efficiently write in a file in C++

Tags: c++, file-system

I've made a program which reads from the console and writes it in a `.txt` file. This programm should write in a file with `\n`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream fich("file.txt");

    if (!fich)
        cerr << "Error!\n";

    char fst = 'l';
    string c;
    while (fst != '\0') {
        getline(cin, c);
        fst = c[0];
        fich << c << endl;
    }

    fich.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This program ends when the user inputs nothing and then a `\n`, because, doing that, the `string c` will only have a `\0` end of string element.

I was wondering if there is any way of doing this more efficiently, maybe without needing a "void `\n`" line to finish the program.

Comment: I guess `main2()` is a typo that should be `main()`, right?

Comment: `c[0]` on an empty string is not guaranteed to be `\0`! Your test should be: `while(getline(std::cin, c)) {` Then you can end input by typing the EOF control code for your platform. `<ctrl>-D` on linux. This also makes it work nicely with files piped to the standard input.

Comment: @uli It was a typo, i corrected it, aprecciate it

Comment: @MartinYork Isn't the string empty when I create it? I thought that if it's empty then the `\0` element should be in `string[0]`.

Comment: Please be aware that changing the code after you have an answer generally isn't permitted because it may invalidate the answer. In this case `main2()` wasn't mentioned in either answer so it is ok. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw I am aware, but `main2()` was just a typo, then I thought it wouldn't be any problem at all. I 'll read it, apreciate it!

Comment: If you just want to copy a file, you can use [`std::filesystem::copy_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file).

Comment: You are thinking of a C-String. The C++ `std::string` class does not use a null terminator. Accessing at `size()` using `operator[]` is undefined behavior. Now there is a method that will give you a null terminated string that looks like a C-String call `c_str()` this guarantees a null terminated string. But why not just call `empty()` to test for an empty string.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I want to write in a file, not copy it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Error Handling

You check whether the output file was opened correctly, but all you do is output a message (you don't even say what's wrong!) and then you keep on ignoring it. What if `file.txt` is a directory or read-only? I guess you haven't tested these cases. By default, throw an exception if you can't continue at some point. In this case, `throw std::runtime_error("failed to open output file")`.

## Loop Condition

You are reading until the line is empty. This is okay-ish, but why don't you just check whether `c.empty()` and then break from the loop? Another case is that the end of the input is reached. In that case, the streamstate is set to failed. I'm not sure what happens in `getline()` then (read the docs at cppreference.com), but if it just doesn't change the string passed by reference, you may end up in an endless loop.

As an alternative I would use `getline(cin, c)` as loop condition. If this succeeds, you have received a line which can then write to the output file. Otherwise, you either had an error or you reached the end of the input.

## Closing Filestreams

If you didn't call `fich.close()`, when would it be closed? However, consider the possibility that the file can't be written fully. You'll never notice this, neither with your code nor if you let the destructor do its work. So, what I'd rather do there is a call to `fiche.flush()` followed by a check of the streamstate.

## Efficiency

I wouldn't bother with that at the moment. Point is, you're still learning to walk, so don't try to run yet. Still, what you're doing is inefficient. Firstly, writing in size of lines is useless, because you're just moving bytes from one file to the other. Secondly, `endl` implies a newline *and* a flush. So this is not really a cheap operation! In addition, there is a lot of stuff going on in C++ IOStreams that there's a whole book about their internals. Lastly, copying files can sometimes be done more efficiently using OS features which will avoid looking at the data more than necessary.

Comment: Yes a file will be closed correctly. The `std::ofstream` destructor calls close. In "most" cases not calling close is the correct action. Also manually calling flush is "usually" the wrong thing to do. The system implementation will auto flush when needed; manually calling flush is the cause of most speed issues in beginners C++ application.

Comment: Speed issues in beginners' applications? Uselessly flushing is a source for bad performance, that much I agree with. However, if you don't flush your stream after you're done writing, you don't know whether the data was written. If there is buffered data that doesn't fit on the storage, you will only get corrupted data and you may not even notice until it's too late.

Comment: _"I'm not sure what happens in getline() then (read the docs at cppreference.com), but if it just doesn't change the string passed by reference, you may end up in an endless loop."_  The string is cleared first.  So if there is an EOF or other problem, you will read an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

The `\0` does not show up as a legal element of the `string`.  In an empty `string`, doing `c[0]` is an error!

You don't need `fst` at all.  You should use `c.empty()` to check for an empty string.

If you're not on a Unix-like system, be sure to open the file in Text mode, or you'll end up with stray `\r` characters in your string.

Your names, `fst`, `fich`, are confusing.  Using `c` for a string is unusual and confusing to experienced programmers.

Don't write `using namespace std;`.

You can use a **mid-decision loop** to simplify your variables and logic.  Something like:

```
for (;;) {
    getline (cin, s);
    if (s.empty()) break;
    outfile << s << '\n';
}
```

As as already been pointed out, the whole idea of reading and writing a line at a time is not "efficient".  It might be what you need, though, for an interactive program where the user is typing something.  If you are implementing something like `cat` though it is less efficient than reading entire blocks using low-level primitives.  The `iostream` implementation reads the file in a low-level way, and `getline` goes through that data (that's already been read into memory) just to locate the end-of-line characters; then copies that to another string.  If you just wanted to copy everything, that's clearly extra overhead.